# Introduce spell checking in Django's template form

Tags: django

When I write a form in Django's template form,
In the opening browser of the form there's not any magic function but a plain blank text area.

How could I introduce the spelling check function to it?

Comment: which function do you use? 3rd party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with plain Browser spellchecking you can just pass the attribute "spellcheck"="true" along with the Textarea.

Example: (Assumes you're using Modelforms and SomeClass with the field text.)

```
from django.forms import Textarea

class SomeClassModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeClass
        fields = ['text']

        widgets = {
            'text': Textarea(attrs={'spellcheck': 'true', 'rows': 5})
        }
```